# AWS API Gateway Access vs Id Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, access-token

What is best practice when it comes to AWS API Gateway Authorization via tokens? Reading mixed messages from AWS in terms of which token to use for API Gateways.
Traditionally, the Access Token is meant of API Authorization via scopes and claims on the token.

However, AWS Cognito allows little flexibility with Access Token claims.
This example on AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-amazon-cognito-to-add-claims-to-an-identity-token-for-fine-grained-authorization/ Even goes as far to us the Id Token for their Authorization. Since you can add/remove claims from the Id Token using the Pregen lambda but you can't with the Access Token.

Am I better off trying to get the Access Token to work in a more creative way for specific users than claims? Can using the Id Token like an Access Token to my API's cause any issues in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using access tokens in APIs is the standard. ID tokens do not contain scopes and do not have the correct lifetime and renewal behavior.

One of the good things about Cognito access tokens is that they do not reveal sensitive token data to internet (web and mobile) clients. This makes them a little similar to reference format access tokens.

You do not have to do JWT authorization in the gateway. In fact an emerging zero trust security model is for each API to verify the JWT itself, to prevent potential threats inside the network.

One option to extend access token claims is to validate the JWT in the API, then look up custom claims (eg from your business data), then add them to a Claims Principal used by your API's logic.

This pattern is followed in [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts#L29), which uses Cognito access tokens. This adds a little complexity, but results in portable API code.

For simpler use cases, using the ID token in APIs may be sufficient and more convenient, as long as you understand the limitations.

Comment: So the idea is that instead of having additional claims added to the Access Token while the Client App is holding it, when an API receives an Access Token, we have each individual API lookup the Access Token's UserInfo (potentially with a sub claim or UserInfo endpoint) and use that information to lookup and append additional claims to the Access Token for the API verify against for each endpoint ?

Comment: or it appears rather than "appending" to the Access Token in your example you are just cacheing the additional custom claims tied to that Access Token.

Comment: That's right - the JWT itself remains unchanged. A better option when supported is for the authorization server to look up the custom claims at the time of token issuance, and include them in the JWT, then return a reference token to the client. When that is not supported, as for Cognito, I would do it this way.